# JQuery: How to add an existing <td> element using its id to a new <tr> element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jinja2

The relevant html for this is:

```
<table class="table" id="constraintTable">
    <tr>
        {% for header in headings %}
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        {% for cell in row%}
        <td>{{ cell }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td id="editDelete">
            <a href="#" id="editRow">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" id="deleteRow">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addConstraint" onclick="constraintAddToTable();>Add New Constraint</button>
```

Now Iam trying to add a row to this table using the following Jquery:
(assuming the 'row' collection in the html above has only 2 entries)

```
function constraintAddToTable() {
    if ($("#constraintTable tbody").length == 0) {
        $("#constraintTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
    }
    
    $("#constraintTable tbody").append("<tr>" +
        "<td>" + "dataval1" + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + "dataval2" + "</td>" +
        $("#editDelete") +  
        "</tr>");
}
```

But this does not work. Only dataval1 and dataval2 gets in and the last column is just blank.
I even tried adding the row without the edit/delete column and later adding the cloumn like this:

```
$("#constraintTable tr: last").append($("#editDelete"))
```

But this doesn't work as well.
Any idea why this doesn't work and what needs to be done instead?

Comment: Solved this by first getting the html() for the element to be added like so: $("#editDelete").html(). Then I expected that the <td> tags and attributes are included too but html() returned just the inner contents excluding the wrapping tags and attr. So finally added them like so:   "<td id='editDelete'>" + $(".editDelete").html() + "</td>" . This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use same `id` for mutliple element instead use `class` .Then , whenever your function gets called you can `clone` your `td.editDelete` and add same inside your generated html using `$(htmls).html()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function constraintAddToTable() {
  if ($("#constraintTable tbody").length == 0) {
    $("#constraintTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
  }
  //get td >first clone it
  var htmls = $("td.editDelete:first").clone()
  //add inside your genearted htmls...
  $("#constraintTable tbody").append("<tr>" +
    "<td>" + "dataval1" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "dataval2" + "</td><td>" +
    $(htmls).html() +
    "</td></tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="constraintTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Soemthing</th>
    <th>Soemthing1</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <!--use class-->
    <td class="editDelete">
      <a href="#" class="editRow">Edit</a>
      <a href="#" class="deleteRow">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td class="editDelete">
      <a href="#" class="editRow">Edit</a>
      <a href="#" class="deleteRow">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addConstraint" onclick="constraintAddToTable();">Add New Constraint</button>
```

Comment: Using same id for multiple elements is not valid HTML however jquery selects the first one. I changed it to class though and applied your code but the result remains the same. The only difference is the dynamic HTML table formation with Jinja. Not sure if that causes the problem.

Comment: Hi, do `console.log(htmls)` see what its giving you and also if you can make jsfiddle with html generated it would be more easy to get exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML code, you don't have `tbody` tag.

Edit your HTML code as below and try.

```
<table class="table" id="constraintTable">
    <tr>
        {% for header in headings %}
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>          //tbody starts
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        {% for cell in row%}
        <td>{{ cell }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td id="editDelete">
            <a href="#" id="editRow">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" id="deleteRow">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>         //tbody ends
</table>
```

Comment: Look at the Jquery code as well. Iam checking for it there. Btw adding tbody like you have said doesnt work.

Comment: Your checking in jQuery code but it will return undefined as there is no tbody tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a copy (clone) and then append. Try this:

```
`$("#constraintTable tr: last").append($("#editDelete").clone(true))`
```